# How to override how Dates are escaped?

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql, node-mysql2

I'm using [node-mysql2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2). I want to override how JavaScript `Date` objects are escaped.

[By default](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values), they are converted to `'YYYY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss'` strings, but I want to store them as integers instead.

How can I do this without reimplementing the entire `queryFormat` function (which parses out `?` and `:namedPlaceholders`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible currently, you'll have to explicitly convert your data before passing as parameters to a query or prepared statement. Might be a good feature - feel free to send pr if you implement it to yourself ( there is already a way to do opposite via custom `typeCast` function - https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#type-casting )

Answer (score 0):

With js `Date` objects you can do `(+yourDate)` to have the corresponding number (in ms) and `(yourDate/1000)` to have an unix time like number.

For example

```
> var a = new Date()
< Mon May 15 2017 22:25:08 GMT+0200 (CEST)

> +a
< 1494879908154

> (a/1000)
< 1494879908.154
```

Comment: Yeah...that's the easy part. How do I integrate this into `node-mysql2`?